# Objective-C - Remove last character from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In Objective-C for iOS, how would I remove the last character of a string using a button action?

Answer (score 424, accepted):

In your controller class, create an action method you will hook the button up to in Interface Builder. Inside that method you can trim your string like this:

```
if ([string length] > 0) {
    string = [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 1];
} else {
    //no characters to delete... attempting to do so will result in a crash
}
```

---

If you want a fancy way of doing this in just one line of code you could write it as:

```
string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-(string.length>0)];
```

---

*Explanation of fancy one-line code snippet:

If there is a character to delete (i.e. the length of the string is greater than 0)

     `(string.length>0)` returns `1`  thus making the code return:

          `string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-1];`

If there is NOT a character to delete (i.e. the length of the string is NOT greater than 0)

     `(string.length>0)` returns `0`  thus making the code return:

          `string = [string substringToIndex:string.length-0];`

     Which prevents crashes.

Comment: Your solution has an off by 1 bug. It should be

[string substringToIndex:[string length] - 1];

Comment: Does "string" refer to "string.text" or just the string name

Comment: Thanks Jim, it was too early in the morning for arithmetic I guess. :)  Omar, string refers to a variable called string that holds the text you want to modify. You can take a look at the documentation for the different ways you can create an NSString object, either from a file on disk or from data in your application.

Comment: @DonalRafferty make sure your string is not nil

Comment: It's okay if string is nil-- calling a method which returns an integer value will return 0 in Obj-C (note that the same is NOT true for floating point return values). So that if statement is equivalent to asking `string != nil && [string length] > 0`. Chances are Donal's string variable is being over released.

Comment: This solution does not take into account composed characters (Unicode letters which take more than one character to encode), and could result in an invalid Unicode string.

Answer (score 54):

If it's an NSMutableString (which I would recommend since you're changing it dynamically), you can use:

```
[myString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([myRequestString length]-1, 1)];
```

Answer (score 8):

The solutions given here actually do not take into account multi-byte Unicode characters ("composed characters"), and could result in invalid Unicode strings.

In fact, the iOS header file which contains the declaration of `substringToIndex` contains the following comment:

> Hint: Use with rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange: to avoid breaking up composed characters

See [how to use `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11760778/1071136) to delete the last character correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation is your friend, `NSString` supports a call `substringWithRange` that can shorten the string that you have an return the shortened String. You cannot modify an instance of `NSString` it is immutable. If you have an `NSMutableString` is has a method called `deleteCharactersInRange` that can modify the string in place

```
...
NSRange r;
r.location = 0;
r.size = [mutable length]-1;
NSString* shorted = [stringValue substringWithRange:r];
...
```

Comment: NSMakeRange can sometimes make filling out a range struct look a little more elegant.

Comment: @Harald, `substringWithRange:` returns a `NSString*`. Take note of the pointer.